# Multivariable functions symmetric in their arguments/representing indexed coefficients

Tags: functions, tensors, indexed-variable

**Context:** I have equations for indexed coefficients $C_{ij}$ which I have represented using 2-variable functions in Mathematica.  e.g.,

```
c[2,1]+c[3,0]==0
c[1,2]+2c[2,1]+c[3,0]==0
```

etc.

Now, my coefficients are symmetric--i.e., $C_{ij}=C_{ji}$ so, when I use functions like Reduce/Solve or Simplify for these equations, I would like Mathematica to recognize $c[1,2]+2c[2,1]=3c[1,2]$, for example.

**Question:** How does one implement this index symmetry in Mathematica?  The implementation of this need not use 2-variable functions; I'd be happy to use a different object type to represent my indexed coefficients.

Comment: Capital `C` has a built in meaning in _Mathematica_, [see here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html). It's generally best not to use capitals so you can avoid conflicts.

Comment: @aardvark2012  good point.  I will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of your notebook, set the attribute of `c` to be `Orderless`.

```
SetAttributes[c, Orderless];
```

Then, all arguments of `c`  will be sorted canonically, allowing you to solve for `c` in your subsequent equations.